# Получить латинскую букву по ID

Tags: java

Например есть метод

```
char getLatin(int i);
```

мне нужно, чтобы данный метод вернул 'a', если `i = 1`, а если `i = 2`, вернёт 'b'. И так далее. Не подскажите как такое можно сделать? Спасибо.

Comment: Можно хранить строку с алфавитом.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
static char getLatin(int i)
{
     if (i>0 && i<27)
 return (char)('A'+i-1);
    else return 'z';
}
```

Comment: или 'a', если нужна строчная.

Comment: 0 пишется как @. Как можно исправить, чтобы было вместо @ был например знак Z. Спасибо

Comment: 'a', если i = 1, а если i = 2,
вы не специфицировали, что делать, если 0. Лучше всего это игнорировать.

Comment: Я подправил ваш код, получилось как - то так (char)('A'+(i == 0 ? 25 : i-1)). Код будет работать правильно, пока не появится новая буква в латинском алфавите :D

Comment: @EnderBro3D при отрицательных не будет работать.

Comment: Спасибо, последний вопрос (можете не отвечать), как обратно вернуть всё что сделали? Например char ch = getLatin(3); (ch == 'c') 
методом int toInt(char ch);

Comment: int i = ch-'a'+1;

Comment: Огромное вам спасибо.